# Start app if its not running in background and received EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification

Tags: ios, eaaccessory

I am developing an iOS app that will stream music to my car using EAAccessory. It works great if I have app running and is open and also works good if app is in the background. But I was just wondering if its possible to start the app if its not running at all(not even in background) and start streaming music as soon as didConnectNotification is received.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is suspended after however long the phone decided to let it run or not running at all, that notification is going to get enqueued. When your app runs again it will then receive the notifications it missed in the queue. So if you miss that window where you are backgrounded before you're killed or simply not running, EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification won't be able to bring your app out of suspension or cause it to launch as far as I know.

Comment: got it.. thanks Dare! Is there a way to prompt user on iPhone like a push notification saying "please launch the app to start streaming" upon successful connection with EAAccessory? Like subscribe to system level event or something like that?

Comment: Under normal circumstances you would be able to post a local notification to do that. But here, unfortunately, the same caveats apply. You app will not know anything happened at all regarding that notification until it gets the chance to run again. If something other than this notification causes your app to run in the background and it notices the accessory is connected, that could trigger a push. The problem is that there's no guarantee in that case when/if your app will run again (in background or foreground) and the push may very well be delayed to the point of being useless or annoying.